# How do I run tests in parallel on same browser / platform?

Tags: intern

There is a config option called "maxConcurrency" which can be used to run same set of tests concurrently on different browser environments, but it's not the same as running tests in parallel.

Is this even possible? Based on Intern homepage, in comparison section, it says Intern supports "Runs tests in parallel for improved performance", which seems total invalid if this is not the case.

Update: I got it confirmed that Intern cannot run tests in parallel on same environment.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with running tests in parallel and what do you mean by parallel?  The comparison section you are referring to is referring to maxConcurrency, which is that your tests can be run on multiple remote environments in concurrently.

Comment: By "parallel", I meant executing tests concurrently and not serially and this on same browser / platform. When you have hundreds of UI tests, it will take hours if you want to run them serially. Could you please confirm that this is not possible with Intern?

Comment: In other words, I'm trying to determine whether or not I can point TheIntern at a Selenium Grid instance and allow it to execute my tests in parallel... if the answer is "yes", can I also run them on multiple platforms/browsers?

Comment: Running multiple tests within a single browser will cause the tests to fail, ergo, a test suite is run serially.  There is nothing preventing you from breaking down your tests into logical groupings that won't interfere with each other and instantiate multiple instances of Intern to run those tests, but as far as a mode of "run my tests all at once so they interfere with each other and cause my results to be invalid", no Intern currently doesn't have that feature.

Comment: questions for @Kitson:
- what do you mean by 'within a single browser will cause the tests to fail'?

Comment: - "run my tests all at once so they interfere with each other and cause my results to be invalid". Interfere each other? that means your tests are poorly designed because they are dependent of each other. Please note I'm talking about UI tests here and not unit tests. I'm not sure if anyone is running UI tests serially anymore, specially those who have hundreds of them, who don't want to end up waiting for the web tests builds for hours.

Comment: Ok, UI tests... So are you suggesting that two tests should be run at the same time in the same browser?  If so, how do you keep the response of the tested application from invalidating the state of the application for the test?  If you are suggesting different browsers on the same machine, again, how do you ensure that be managed via Selinium so the mouse can be in two places at the same time?  Can you provide an example of where someone is actually running two or more UI tests in the same environment at the same time, because I am clearly missing something.

Comment: To clarify, I mean "different browsers on the same machine". From your response I see that you do not have much experience in Selenium. This is silly comment - "mouse can be in two places at the same time".
So please would suggest learn more about Selenium before commenting. Thanks!